# Vue: can't use a component inside another compontent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I am trying to use a child compontent in another compontent and it does not work. I have been trying to solve this problem looking for typos etc. for hours, but can't find anything.

**Menu.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class='navbar-and-alert'>
        <alert/>
        <nav class='navbar'>

        </nav>
    </div>

</template>

<script>


    import Alert from './Alert.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'Navbar',
        compontents: {
            Alert
        },
        data (){
            return {

            }
        },
    }

</script>
```

**Alert.vue**

```
<template>

    <section class='alert-section'>
        <p class='alert-section__content'>
            ...
        </p>
        <a href=''><img src='/static/assets/img/close.svg' class='alert-section__close-icon'></a>
    </section>

</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'Alert',
}

</script>
```

I get this alert in console:

> Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>   found in

**The alert component works when used inside App.vue**

Comment: Can you confirm if you have a typo in the Vue constructor options, specifically "compontents" instead of `components`?

Answer (score 1):

`components` has a typo:

```
compontents: {
    Alert
},
```

Should be:

```
components: {
    Alert
},
```